# How can I create an arbitrary file in a bash script and how is it possible to delete a created file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

How can I create a random file using bash on Linux and how is it possible to delete a created file? I am not sure.

Idea: The user should enter an arbitrary file name and save it. They can also delete this saved file.

Thanks in advance

Code to delete a file:

```
    if [ "$REPLY" = "d" ];                                                                             

        then

        read -r -p 'Delete file: Please enter the name of the file to delete: ' -a delete_file 

        echo -e "\nFile was deleted: ${delete_file[*]}\n"                                  

        break

    fi
```

Comment: Do you want a random file name or do you want the user to choose a file name?

Comment: A random file name. Users should enter a name and confirm it.

Comment: Those are mutually exclusive: _either_ the user enters a name, _or_ you want to generate a random name. Which one do you want?

Comment: The first one. The user enters a name.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file using the `>` redirection operator wither with a command (`command > file`) or by itself:

```
> file
```

Note that this will overwrite the contents of `file` if a file with that name already exists. If no such file exists, an empty one will be created.

Alternatively, you can use the `touch` command which will also create a file if a file with the name you give it doesn't already exist, but will not overwrite the contents of an existing file. If a file with that name exists, the `touch` command will update its modification timestamp:

```
touch file
```

So, in a script, if you want to prompt the user for a file name and create it, you could do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a file name: " fileName
echo "You entered: '$fileName'"

while [ -e "$fileName" ]; do
   read -p "A file named '$fileName' already exists, delete? [y/n]: "
   if [ "$REPLY" = "y" ]; then
     rm -- "$fileName"
   else
      read -p "Enter a different file name: " fileName
   fi
done

touch -- "$fileName"
```

To make a file with a random name, the best tool is `mktemp` which will make sure that the name is unique in the target directory (see `man mktemp` for details):

```
$ randomFileName=$(mktemp)
$ echo "$randomFileName"
/tmp/tmp.QLLdNLFBFd
```

Comment: I will try it. Thank you.